# ADF Tree Table Expanding Parent Nodes

Tags: tree, hierarchy, oracle-adf, treetable

### [Hierarchy Relationship Table]

---

I am creating a **Tree Table** from a very large dataset.
The Hierarchy Master detail relation is established by Creating a

1. Query Based **ViewObject**.
2. **ViewLink** between **CHILDDNODE** and **PARENTNODE** as on table
3. **ViewCriteria** in **ViewObject** as **GROUPBY PARENTNODE = NULL**

The problem I am facing is when the tree table is running every time I expand a parent **NODE** I have to wait for 1 min or more to get it expand.

Answer (score 0):

That is default af:tree behaviour: every collapse/expand will basically re-query the children.

You can avoid that by setting Retain View Link Accessor Rowset property in VO: http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/tuning-adf-tree-retain-view-link.html